# combine values from two separate rows into one row using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to combine certain values from separate columns into one 'cell':

**Data**

```
hello   hi      ok      bye
q122    q222    q422    q222
hi      hi      hi      hi
```

**Logic**

```
The first two rows are joined
```

[image]

**Desired**

```
hello_q122  hi_q222   ok_q422   bye_q222
            
hi          hi        hi        hi
```

**Doing**

```
df.replace('').groupby('hello',as_index=False).agg(''.join)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the input as dataframe constructor and the logic for the joining (how to select the rows that are joined), your current `groupby` makes no sense)

Comment: yes thank you it does